# Performance hit with new hard drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, performance

I've recently upgraded my laptop's internal hard drive from a 160GB to 1TB drive. I cloned the drive, then installed it. The general system performance seems appreciably slower. In particular application launches seem to take much longer. Is this possible, or am I just expecting too much from the new drive?

It's running a Macbook Pro which is a couple of years old. Any ideas?

```
160 GB  7MB cache  5400 rpm    NCQ  (Hitachi HTS545016B9SA02) -- original drive
1   TB  8MB cache  5400 rpm  SATA300  NCQ  (Western Digital WD10TPVT-00HT5T0)
```

Sisoftware links:

- [Hitachi HTS545016B9SA02](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/rank2009/show_run.php?q=c2ffcefadcbddce1d0e4d6e5d1f785b888aecbae93a385f6cbface&l=en)
- [Western Digital WD10TPVT-00HT5T0](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/rank2009/show_run.php?q=c2ffccfcdabbdae7d6e4d4e6d1f785b888aecbae93a385f6cbf8&l=en)

Comment: The spindle speed is slower. Also, look at the bottom of this link: http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/feedback/1tb_wd_scorpio_in_macs.html

Comment: @Randolf Potter - thanks for the link, but I can't find any info about spindle speed on that page... Surely my WD can't be _slower_ than 5400rpm?

Answer (score 1):

It may simply be a slower drive - not all drives are equal. There are a fair number of things that can affect performance - caching strategy, number of platters, and so on. In addition, all other things being equal, larger drives tend to have a little more overhead. If you want to test your drives to see if there's actually a performance difference, try something like [Xbench](http://www.xbench.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the Xbench tip. Although I've not yet tested my old drive, Xbench does show that my new drive is freakishly and consistently slow in some areas. It gets a score of ~14 for 4k random writes, and ~55 for sequential and random 4k reads. The latter, I think, pertains to application launches, so cheers for helping me figure that one out.